# Partial sums of the Dedekind zeta function

Tags: number-theory, zeta-functions, computer-algebra-systems, sagemath, magma-cas

Is there a way to find the partial sums of the Dedekind zeta function? In particular, I would like to find the sum $$\sum_{0 \neq I \subset\mathcal{O}_K \\N(I) \le n} \frac{1}{N(I)^s}$$
for a given $n$ and $s$?

Edit.
For quadratic numbeer fields, by using the identity $\zeta_K(s)=\zeta(s)L(s,\chi)$ as here:
[Properties of Dedekind zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/648762/properties-of-dedekind-zeta-function?rq=1)
I can able to find the value of partial sums of $\zeta_K(s)$. For example, for cyclotomic number fields, the same method works too. However, I look for a *function* etc. defined in the computer algebra system.

Comment: Find out how the prime ideals behave in your ring of integers. Then you know which ideals have norm small $n$ and you can sum it up.

Comment: What do you mean with "find" ? $\frac{\zeta_K(s+z)}{z}$ is the Mellin transform of $\sum_{0<N(I) \le x} N(I)^{-s}$. For a multiplicative function $a_n$ in general there is no easy way to compute $\sum_{n\le x} a_n$.

Comment: Okay, I mean for example in the case $s=1$, we can proceed as in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92426/how-many-elements-in-a-number-field-of-a-given-norm.

What about $s=2,3, $etc.?